# highcharts map add image to tooltip

Tags: javascript, highcharts, tooltip, highmaps

I had trouble to add images to Highmap bubble tooltip when hover over bubbles. Anyone knows how to fix it?

Thanks a lot

Here is an example link. Images added on line 24: http://jsfiddle.net/1jm2yxbq/

```
tooltip: {
formatter: function () {
return '<img src="http://www.w3schools.com/tags/smiley.gif" width="42" height="42">';
}},
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You just need to set the `useHTML` property to `true`:

```
tooltip: {
              useHTML: true,
              formatter: function () {
                     return '<img src="http://www.w3schools.com/tags/smiley.gif" width="42" height="42">';
                }
            },
```

I tested it out on the fiddle and it works fine: http://jsfiddle.net/1jm2yxbq/1/

Comment: Thanks a lot for you help!