# Image logo on hover using datamaps

Tags: html, datamaps

I'm working with datamaps. Learning by jumping in to examples.

This is the demo that is provided: http://jsbin.com/nutawiboci/1/edit?html,output

I'm trying to get a logo to show up on the hover - as in mouse over a bubble and you get a string and an image, say img https://www.w3schools.com/tags/smiley.gif

When I try and add this into the popupTemplate using img src="image url here" alt="smiley", the code doesn't run.

```
popupTemplate: function(geo, data) {
return "<div class='hoverinfo'>It is " + data.name + "</div>";
}
```

[highcharts map add image to tooltip](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40557751/highcharts-map-add-image-to-tooltip) - this is the closest to what I'm looking for, but I still can't get it to work for datamaps.

Could you please help? Thank-you.

Comment: What do you mean by "it breaks" ?

Comment: Sorry - it means when I add in what I think should go in to input a picture, like 
    popupTemplate: function(geo, data) {
    return "<div class='hoverinfo'>It is " + data.name + 
    }<img src="https://www.w3schools.com/tags/smiley.gif" alt="smiley face"+ "</div>";
 it doesn't work. I know there's something wrong with how I input the image, but I don't know what. Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The `popupTemplate` inside the code works, but it is called for the rounded bubbles of the above array. I also tried adding the smiley img and it works fine.

If you want to put a custom popup over geographic regions, you have to add `geographyConfig` to `Datamap` initialization, with the `popupTemplate`, e.g. after the `data`:

```
var map = new Datamap({
    ...
    data: {...}

    geographyConfig: {
      popupTemplate: function(geo, data) {
        return "<div class='hoverinfo'>It is " + geo.properties.name + "</div>";
      }
    }
}
```

Here there is the working sample: http://jsbin.com/zojuqideto/edit?html,output

Comment: That's it! Thanks! I think I had " ' issues. From a beginner - thanks for taking the time.