# Adding images to tooltips in Highmaps

Tags: highcharts

How can I a display an image (small icon) in a tooltip within Highmaps?
I know this question has been asked before - [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40557751/highcharts-map-add-image-to-tooltip) - but damned if I can get it to work. I even wonder if it is possible, because as far as I can see in their API docs, the Highmaps support for HTML is limited, as eg [here](https://api.highcharts.com/highmaps/tooltip.formatter) and does not include the img tag.

I have create a jsfiddle [here](https://jsfiddle.net/philu/3n9at5d0/9/) with some sample icons.  I'd be grateful if someone could demo how to add these to the tooltips (one per tooltip, of course)

```
$('#container').highcharts('Map', {
        title: {
           "text": "Simple Map"
        },
        series: [
            {
              "name": "Colours",
                "type": "map",
                "tooltip": {
                   "headerFormat": "",
                   "pointFormat": "{point.name}"
                },
                "data": [
                    {
                        "name": "Blue<br>violets",
                        "path": "M0,-994L204,-994L203,-480,0,-477z"
                    },
                    {
                        "name": "Yellow<br>is the colour of...",
                        "path": "M204,-994L455,-994L457,-477,203,-480z"
                    },
                    {
                        "name": "Red<br>sky at night",
                        "path": "M455,-994,697,-991,700,-481,457,-477z"
                    },
                    {
                        "name": "Green<br>grass",
                        "path": "M697,-991,998,-992,1000,-480,700,-481z"
                    }
                ]   
            }
        ]
     });
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to enable the `useHTML` parameter and link a displayed picture with a point, for example:

```
series: [{
    ...,
    "data": [{
            ...,
            tooltipImg: 'left'
        },
        {
            ...,
            tooltipImg: 'right'
        },
        ...
    ]
}],
tooltip: {
    useHTML: true,
    formatter: function() {
        return this.point.name +
        '<br><img src="http://icons.iconarchive.com/icons/saki/nuoveXT/128/Small-arrow-' +
        this.point.tooltipImg + '-icon.png" width="32" height="32">'
    }
}
```

**Live demo:** https://jsfiddle.net/BlackLabel/9bujq56y/

**API Reference:** https://api.highcharts.com/highmaps/tooltip.useHTML

Comment: OK silly me - I had the tooltip block inside the series block when it should be outside of it. Don't know how I managed that. Strangely enough, some of its functions do work even when wrongly placed so - but not the formatter - which was why I hadn't clocked my own silly mistake.